# JQuery Element ID as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JQuery code example:

```
 $("#addPrev").one("click", function() {
    $('#1').before(prevElement); 
 });
```

Im trying in my application to add elements dynamically.

Is it possible to replace the ('#1') with a variable for example(ID),
of course the id would be defined and related to the right one.

I am thankful for every tip or solution! Cheers!

Comment: Did you try it before asking and it didn't work?

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: yes I tried it before and did not work :(

Comment: Nothing abut what you are suggesting seems problematic-- perhaps you should post the code you tried that is _not_ working so the community can better understand what you are trying and show you how to correct it?

Comment: Like `var myId = 'myId'; $('#' + myId)...;` ?

Comment: should it be always be a string? @nurdyguy

Comment: What it *should* be depends entirely on what you are trying to do.  `$()` expects a string selector, or a dom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the variable but keep the hash

```
$("#addPrev").one("click", function() {
    $('#' + variableName).before(prevElement); 
});
```